# The applicability of the Master Theorem and calculation of asymptotic limits

Tags: asymptotics, master-theorem

Given the following recursive equation
$T(n)=3T(\dfrac{n}{8})+ Θ(n^{1/3})$

I want to know how to explain the applicability of the Master theorem in a rigorous
 way and what means asymtotic limits of complexity exactly?

I remarked the two cases are not satisfied. So I have to check the third case and i saw that
$n^{1/3} \notin Ω(n^{1/3*log_2⁡ 3 + ε})$

Comment: The first case applies since $1/3 < \log_8 3$.

Comment: @ssrvz $1 = \log_2 2 < \log_2 3$. $\log$ is (strictly) monotonically increasing.

Comment: Also, by explaining the "applicability of the master theorem" do you mean determining whether the master theorem applies to $T$ or not?

Comment: Yes, to determinate whether the master theorem applies to T.